# Two-way unsupervised learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have two data sets, A and B. Both have a large number of continuous variables. I believe that A is related to B. But there are no defined classes in either A or B. I could do a bunch of correlation tests to see if any of the variables in A are strongly correlated with B. But many variables in A are likely dependent on each other, and the same is true for B. I could perform unsupervised learning on both A and B and try to associate the clusters from each. But because the clusters for A are derived without knowledge of B, the A clusters may not be as relevant to B as they could be. Here's my question. Is there an area of machine learning and/or statistics that is focused on this type of problem? If so, where can I look?

Comment: I feel that canonical correlation analysis is what can suit you.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by {A|B} clusters: the body of your question suggests either clusters of variables or cases, while the title looks like it has more to do with two unlabeled classes (of cases)?

Comment: In the second option I describe, I am talking about associating clusters of variables in A with clusters of variables in B. Sorry about the title. I wasn't sure how to describe it, so I made it vague.

Comment: What types of things would you like to discover or do?  CCA (as @ttnphns suggests) will find you the linear combinations of variables in your A dataset and in your B dataset that are maximally correlated.  Partial least squares regression may also be relevant to you. If this is the right track, we can expand this answer more... Or do you have some third variable you are trying to predict using A and B together?

Comment: CCA looks useful to some extent. What I really want to do is use A to predict B. But I don't want to predict individual variables in B. I believe there is complex structure in B, so I want first to identify that structure in B and then see how well I can predict that structure with A. But at the same time, A has complex structure, so I also want to identify structure that exists in A and use that to predict B. Not sure if I'm using valid terminology here, but hopefully it gets my point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at these papers:

[F. Bach, M. I. Jordan. A probabilistic interpretation of canonical correlation analysis. Technical Report 688, Department of Statistics, University of California, Berkeley, 2005](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/probacca.pdf)

and

[Cédric Archambeau, Nicolas Delannay, and Michel Verleysen. 2006. Robust probabilistic projections. In Proceedings of the 23rd international conference on Machine learning (ICML '06).](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.archambeau/publ/icml_ca06.pdf)

They both give graphical model interpretations of CCA, form it as (slightly different) probabilistic models, and show how these can be solved using the EM algorithm.

Whilst it might not exactly match your requirements, it seems that your problem could be formulated as a graphical model in this way. Depending how the resulting model looks, you might be able to use off-the-shelf methods to solve it - see e.g. [this list of software packages](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnsoft.html)